# How to playback from two speakers?

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, oboe

I have Pixel 2XL and this device has 2 speakers one at the top and one at the bottom.

So, for sound playback I am using oboe lib

https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/samples/hello-oboe

but I noticed that sound is playing just from one speaker that is on top.

But for example there is an app on PlayMarket - SoundCloud and if I try to playback something from this app I hear that sound goes from two speakers from top and from bottom one.

So, I assume that there is should be a setting on oboe lib in order to set how I need to playback a sound from which speaker and so on.

But I did not find anything about it.

How to do it?

Comment: That is strange. The hello-oboe app will output a different pitch sine wave on each channel. So you should hear a low pitch sound from the top speaker and a higher pitch sound from the bottom speaker (just tested on Pixel 2 - not XL). Do you hear a single tone (indicating that only one channel of the audio stream is being played) or 2 tones together (indicating that both channels are being played from a single speaker)?

Answer (score 1):

The channelCount is set on the builder using setChannelCount(cc)
https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/d27324865282e8d8497bdc6652df98d3f2f0f6c7/samples/hello-oboe/src/main/cpp/HelloOboeEngine.cpp#L93

You cannot direct the sound to specific speakers. The routing is determined by the phone.

I tried Hello-Oboe on a Pixel 2 XL. If I cover the top speaker with my thumb then the sound definitely changes. So it is playing through the top speaker on my device.

Perhaps some app let the phone in a state where it is treating the top speaker as an earpiece.  Try rebooting the phone. Does it now sound louder in the top speaker?